# Using jq to shows all possible jq paths and their values and handle cases where numbers are object keys

Tags: jq

Working off of https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/243, I've got an almost complete solution to be able to generate the jq paths to access all elements within a json object. But unfortunately it isnt producing a valid jq path if there is an object key is a number.

The path to the object key needs to be quoted to be correctly handled, but I cant seem to get the syntax correct.

The query looks like:

```
# source: https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/243

def path2text($value):
  def tos: if type == "number" then . else (tojson) end;
  reduce .[] as $segment ("";  .
    + ($segment
       | if type == "string" then "." + . else "[\(.)]" end))
  + " = \($value | tos)";
  

paths(scalars) as $p
  | getpath($p) as $v
  | $p | path2text($v)
```

A sample json object showing the problem is:

```
{ "00" : "a" }
```

[The query will produce](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/?#v2=N4IglgdgDgrgLgFQKYA84gFwmAAgDogAMhBOG+IAhqQL4gA0IAZmADZxIBOAoilJ5hAATJExxRKcABYAmDmgAUAEgBulVjCQBKDHgg4cIsXAD2AZ3JhjATyhIcAXgcUIMALYAjLqWlJ9AOhwkVjN7BVMAKzMTCC0giCEAbj0DTiQhGABje38AbQBdHEozHCVQgHM3PzgcBQICRIN-FIMcAGpasqRK6pbWgwAfHCscOFt7JwozOE5Icp8pPwpmkHacQODQily8PAV-LXzSPyEtLRaO0mdd5TUNeyHTM3OQZP18CD0JaTMFM0z1JROM8iiUlFAWkNykg4N8pMooHFiqUVJDSlAcEM4XJUHBbloGCBOJQAO4AeXgsHQGCY6lCNCAA):

```
".00 = \"a\"
```

But using that filter on the same object will produce the following error:

```
1 compile error
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[0].0   
jq: 1 compile error
```

The correct filter should be:

```
."00"
```

I've made a couple attempts trying to use the test function and a regex, but I can't quite get it right. My closest version is:

```
def quote_string_numbers($data):
   if (test("\\.\\d+") or test("\\d+")) then "\"" + . + "\"" else . end;

def path2text($value):
  def tos: if type == "number" then . else tojson end;
  reduce .[] as $segment ("";  .
    + ($segment
       | if type == "string" then 
            quote_string_numbers("." + .) else "[\(.)]" end))
  + " = \($value | tos)";

paths(scalars) as $p
  | getpath($p) as $v
  | $p | path2text($v)
```

But that still isnt quite right and while it produces [correct results for my example](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/?#v2=N4IglgdgDgrgLgFQKYA84gFwmAAgDogAMhBOG+IAhqQL4gA0IAZmADZxIBOAoilJ5hAATJExwBHGAHsOAfQDOcTpADmsiDAC2AIy7yAFABIhlOJQCUGPBBy2wY-R0X6CeN3gB07vEIDUBcxwpThwnOBcQbz8AwLgACyQbVzdIkBxfHA90indUnCRWeSRM-IghAG5raxExKFM4gCYONCMAN0pWGCRLa1sa0Kl5cntQgE8oYoBeSYoNHS5SeMSSgqKBgCt5KRtEit6cTiQhGABjYo8AbQBdHEp5HEMilU1EuBwIgnLbLxtbbKMni8IHB9n9bAAfHAjODjKYzAiKZQQFSLBJJX5gzESaRyRGqdRaXScAwELxpDIeQKrYoEC5ufSUq6kXbmcz7DKkeF4NodLo4SFwQZskCVCDWOrxAzyE4dSjEwJ3B5QfaQlRIOASuJGKAK+6GVoqpX8nCapqocL68wMECcSgAdwA8vBYOgMEwOkUaEA).

```
"\"00\" = \"a\""
```

But it doesnt for a more complex case:

```
{ "00" : {"02" : "a", "banana" : "foo" }}
```

[instead it produces](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/?#v2=N4IglgdgDgrgLgFQKYA84gFwmAAgDogAMhBOGOwBhATKeQQIYEA0+IARgxF0yGWwDMA9kNIBfMSGYgBYADZwkAJwCiKKEswgAJkgE4AjjCGKA+gGc4SyAHNTEGAFt2y8wAoAJNoZwGASgw8CBwQsH03RUs3AjxYvAA6OLxtAGoCPxwhJRxIuGiQJNT0jLgACyRgmNiCvhSceJw6qpi+JDlzJHqcCu0AbiCg3X0oH1LqRTRPADcGORgkAKCQoZyhc3IwnIBPKE6AXj22B2dlUjKKrraO1YArcyFgnv7gnCUkbRgAY074gG0AXRwDHMOA8HRsjgqcBw+QIvRCiReITqnnBkIgcCWIWxOAAPjhNnAdvtDgRLNYIDYzuVKkicfSjCYkBYrLZ7E4XEp3ARErV6hkrp0CL9Ym54n5-qQen4-FimnxSXhprN5njVuZZSBnkERmV3OZPrMGFyMsDQVAsfibEg4LrSp4oKaQR4ppbzWq7eNUHkXX4pCAlAwAO4AeXgsHQGAEsw6YiAA):

```
"\"00\"\"02\" = \"a\""
"\"00\"banana = \"foo\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would create the desired output:

- `tostream` produces a stream of path-only items and path-value pairs; filter for those having a value (using `select(has(1))`) to get the scalars (alternatively, use `paths(scalars)` and `getpath`)
- in the path array, strings represent object fields, numbers represent array indices; convert them separately using `strings` and `numbers`, respectively, then prepend the dot (since jq 1.7, a dot preceding array indices in brackets is valid syntax even in concatenated expressions)

```bash
tostream | select(has(1))  # or: paths(scalars) as $p | [$p, getpath($p)]
| "\(first | map(".\("[\(numbers)]" // strings|=@json)") | add) = \(last|@json)"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TbE97EehbOg)

Comment: Could use `if test("^[0-9]|[^A-Za-z0-9_]") then tojson end` for the string case. So it's only quoting when needed.

Comment: Thanks for both of these parts, I combined them to get a solution that didn't create additional edge cases, and solved my use case:

`tostream | select(has(1))
| "\(first | map(".\("[\(numbers)]" // strings|=if test("^[0-9]|[^A-Za-z0-9_]") then tojson end)") | add) = \(last|@json)"`